# Making Fixed Side-bar stop scrolling before footer

Tags: jquery

I know this question has been asked a million times - but I have tried every solution I can find and none of them seem to work.

This is a WordPress site - the sidebar works great when scrolling down. But I want it to stop scrolling with the user before the footer (200px at bottom of page or so).

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
       $('#sidebar').css('position','fixed').css('top', '100px').css('left', '69.5%').css('width', '20%');
   } else {
       $('#sidebar').css('position','static').css('width', '25%');
   }

 });
```

Above is my working code to make the sidebar sticky.

Answer (score 0):

I really can't understand well what you trying to do .. but .. this may help

```
// get window height
$(window).height(); //you can use  - 200

// get document full height
$(document).outerHeight(true); //you can use  - 200

// get -200px before #footer element 
$('#footer').offset().top - 200
```

and about your code you can simplify it like:

```
$('#sidebar').css({'position':'fixed',
                   'top': '100px',
                   'left': '69.5%',
                   'width': '20%'});
```

Comment: I am essentially trying to make the sidebar position change from fixed to absolute when it reaches a certain point on the page.

Comment: @user3400029 try to define elementPosition inside scroll event .. and let me know what is going on .. but please with that kind of question its better to make [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @user3400029 see this http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/bh9hj68r/1/ and make your update